# Logs for SQL queries in Java using Eclipse

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, sql-server-2008, logging

If I am using the below code query the database, where would I find the log file for the process?  I am looking for what is being sent to the database.  The query works from SQL Server Management Studio. The database is MS-SQL 2008.

```
 try{
 Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");

        String userName = "dbuser";
        String password = "dbpswd";
        String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server:1043"+";databaseName=databasename";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
        Statement stm = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery
                ("SELECT users.id,users.role FROM users WHERE users.username = 'xusername' AND users.password = 'xpswd' AND users.active = 1");
 }
```

When the code runs it returns

```
 'No current row in the ResultSet.'
```

If I use

```
 System.out.println(stm);
```

it returns

```
 net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement@7fd2c698
```

Comment: System.out.println(stm); prints you the object reference to the console... Sent to the database is the SQL query (and obviously the authentication information). Besides that your code works fine. Otherwise you'd get an exception. How many results are you expecting?

Comment: I new to java so please bear with me.  I was expecting one result.  I used Chris311 suggestion in the form of while(rs.next()){System.out.println(rs.getString("id"));} and I get my result.  So how do you get your result if you are only expecting one result? Do you have to use the while loop?

Comment: Sometimes it is nice to see the query that is received by the database from the code.  Is there a way to capture that in eclipse/java setup?  I come from ColdFusion and when it has an error the debugging will provide the query.

Comment: You need a while loop if you expect multiple results. Otherwise a rs.next(); would be enough. (check if it returns true or false. The latter would mean you got an empty resultSet). I suggest you have a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

Comment: You can assign the SQL-query to a String variable instead of passing it directly. That way you can log it. Besides that you might want to look into prepared statements. This won't fix the issue with displaying the SQL statement but I'd recommend it for security reasons ;)

Comment: Understood just looking for debugging options while I learn.  That way I know what issue I am fighting with.  Wrong function or bad syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use

```
rs.next()
```

to retrieve the first entry. A `ResultSet` cursor is initially positioned before the first row.

Comment: Thanks Chris311.  I am new to java. I used this while(rs.next()){System.out.println(rs.getString("id"));} and got my result.  Do you have to use a while loop when you are expecting only one result?

Comment: @user1088014 No, you don't have to.